# error when parsing json data with swift "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Tags: php, json, database, swift

anyone who knows about retrieving data from a database and using it to check if a user exits (sign in) please help. My head is wrecked and unfortunately my coding is not quite good enough to fix the problem!

```
 do {


                if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
                {


                    let parseJSON = json

                    let userID = parseJSON["userId"] as? String //dictionary object that uses a key

                    if(userID != nil)
                    {
                        //everything is fine and take user to main page 
                        //instantiate the view controller
                        let profilePage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfilePageViewController") as! ProfilePageViewController

                        //wrap it in nav controller

                        let profilePageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profilePage)

                        //take user to this page
                        //window root view controller- existing is replaced and no back button

                        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
                        appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = profilePageNav




                    }else{
                        //display the alert message from the php file
                        let errorMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String


                        let myAlert = UIAlertController(
                            title: "Alert!",
                            message: errorMessage,
                            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                        //create a button action -
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

                        //adding ok button and presenting to a user and once ok button is pressed- dismiss the view
                        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion:nil)





                    }


                }//end of if let json
            }//end of do
            catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }



            print("success")

        }//end of dispatch_async
    }).resume()//end of request




}//end of action sign in
```

I think the issue is with the if let json = try line, the data is not in the correct format. My php script is working well and I can pass parameters in the browser and all seems ok. The key is correct (userId).
I think another issue is with let userID = parseJSON["userId"] as? String

if I have made a request for the data as an NSDictionary - how can I convert this info to type String (I'm sure you can't anyways) Sorry - a lot of questions. I need String representations to use in another view controller. I have been trying this for ages and I can't get it to work so I would really appreciate some help- 
When i run the code- it bypasses the "do" block and goes straight to the .localizedDescription

Thank you for talking the time to read my v long question!

Comment: What is the JSON string returned from API?

Comment: The string is returning userId from the phpmyadmin database- user_id is set as auto increment and its value as Int- could this be causing the problem? I have to auto increment to number users and have the email as the unique identifier

Comment: NO- I've answered my own question- it has nothing to do with the fact that userId is an Int- tried to parse a varchar value and got the same error

Answer (score 1):

The issue is definitely in NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData which doesn't like your JSON for some reason.

Try cleaning your JSON before feeding it to NSJSONSerialization:

```
var dataString = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
dataString = dataString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\'", withString: "'")
let cleanData: NSData = dataString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Answer (score 0):

while sending a request "request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")" resolved my error.