# Swift3.2 how to know where the log come from?

Tags: swift, xcode, console

**Edit:** This log is not print by myself, and I also don't know where/who print it. I've did all the search methods in my Xcode. **I just want to know if any method/chance to make Xcode shows more information in console for logs.**

p.s.: please do not subtract my points, I'm a cheaper

---

I got a warning/error log from console but I don't know where it come from:

[image: logs]

How to shows the name of the logger?

Comment: Did you try [searching on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+data+couldn%27t+be+read+because+it+isn%27t+in+the+correct+format)?

Comment: Check in your code where ever you are trying to print server response.

Comment: Please post the error (text), not an image of the error.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351304/error-when-parsing-json-data-with-swift-the-data-couldn-t-be-read-because-it-is

Comment: I've did all of you guys suggestions, but not found

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the code, the only thing you can do is search for that string in the source files; '`The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format.`'

Comment: Then you need to search your non-Apple frameworks and libraries. 
That is not from any Apple code.